# How do I match the inner pattern multiple times instead of the outer patterns that is similar?

Tags: linux

I would like to match an inner patterns that are subsets of the greater outer pattern using egrep. For example:

```
$ egrep 'b.*a' <<< baababaa
baababaa
```

I want it to print:

```
baa
ba
baa
```

Comment: `echo "baababaa" | sed 's/\(.\)b/\1 b/g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`egrep` isn't really the correct tool for the job due to `grep` limitations with output control. Instead, `sed` can provide exactly what you need using *basic* regular expressions.

For example:

```
$ echo "baababaa" | sed 's/\(.\)b/\1 b/g'
baa ba baa
```

**Explanation**

- `sed 's/find/replace/g'` - general substitution form of `sed` with the `'g'` option applied to make the replacements *global*, where

*find*

- `'.'` - match any single-character, and
- `\(.\)` - capture the single-character between the `\(...\)`,
- followed by a `'b'`,

*replace*

- `\1` insert the back-reference (the character captured between `\(...\)`),
- followed by a `' '` (space) and `'b'`.

A more limited form that simply finds all inner `"ab"` and puts a space between them would be:

```
sed 's/ab/a b/g'
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.